# Django Static Files Not Serving On Development With Proper Config

Tags: django, django-settings

I have my project laid out like this:
Project
App1
App2

My static folder is in Project with 2 directories like so:
-/Project/static/css
-/Project/static/js

I have the following config in my settings.py file:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

However I am getting 404s on any files served from there. I have 'django.contrib.staticfiles', in my INSTALLED_APPS constant and my static constants set like:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH + '/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media'

STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH + '/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static'
```

What could I be doing wrong? I get nothing but 404s and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: well, do you see the `STATIC_URL` in the url conf on the 404 page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was setting STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT when I should have been setting this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    PROJECT_PATH + '/static/',
)
```